# Include Hyperref Text Field in a UML State Diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, hyperref, pgfkeys, forms, tikz-uml

As you can see in my minimal example, I have a state machine diagram where students can write the name of the transition line in a text box. Can you give me some advice on how to place a text field inside the state waiting?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc, shadings, shadows, shapes.arrows,fit, arrows.meta, matrix, mindmap}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    transition textfield extension/.style n args = {4}{
        color=black,
        rounded corners, 
        arrows={-Straight Barb[angle=60:9pt 2]},
        insert path={node[minimum size=12pt,yshift=0.5cm,xshift=#2] at  ($(#3)!#1!(#4)$){\TextField[name=name,width=2cm,height=1em,multiline=false,bordercolor=black, charsize=9pt]{}}},
    }]
    \begin{umlstate}[name=Statemaschine]{Lightcontrol}
        \umlstateinitial[name=start,x=0,y=3]{start}
        \umlbasicstate [below left=5of start,fill=red!20, width=5cm] {waiting}
        \umlHVtrans[transition textfield extension={.1}{-3cm}{start}{waiting}]{start}{waiting}
    \end{umlstate}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether I understood you correctly, but if you want to place a text field inside the state node, can just `name` the state node and add a regular `\node` which you can place at the `center` anchor of the state node. This would be the cleanest solution in my opinion. I really don't think that it is necessary to use something like `insert path` here.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    transition extension/.style={
        arrows={-Straight Barb[angle=60:9pt 2]},
    }]
    \begin{umlstate}[name=Statemaschine]{Lightcontrol}
        \umlstateinitial[name=start, x=0,y=3]{start}
        \umlbasicstate[below left=5 of start, fill=red!20, width=5cm, name=waiting] {waiting}
        \umlHVtrans[transition extension]{start}{waiting}
    \end{umlstate}
    \node[anchor=north] at (waiting.center) {\TextField[name=name, width=2cm, height=1em, multiline=false, bordercolor=black, charsize=9pt]{}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is probably reasonable to enclose the final with `\begin{Form}` ... `\end{Form}`.